# Get value of Centos version

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

When i run `cat /etc/redhat-release` I get the output

`CentOS Linux release 7.5.1708`

I only want to get the value `7` out of it

I have written the following but it is not working

`cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F. '{print $1}`

Comment: cat /etc/redhat-release | grep -o 7

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the number, not the awk thing, here is a way much easier:

```
. /etc/os-release
echo $VERSION_ID
```

**Why?**

Check the man page `man os-release`

> The basic file format of os-release is a newline-separated list of
>   environment-like shell-compatible variable assignments. It is possible
>   to source the configuration from shell scripts...

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the nicest solution, but since you know the file will begin with "CentOS Linux release ", you could use `cut` to take just the 22d character after that prefix:

```
$ cut -c22 /etc/redhat-release
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'.' '{sub(/.*[^0-9]/,"",$1); print $1}' <<< $(< /etc/redhat-release)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need awk and if you could use the `/etc/os-release` give a try to:

```
awk -F '=' '/^VERSION_ID/ {print $2}' /etc/os-release
```

But maybe will need to unquote by using `| tr -d '"'`

Using grep:

```
grep -oP 'VERSION_ID="\K[^"]+' /etc/os-release
```

The `\K` excludes the `VERSION_ID="` and the `[^"]+` means to keep matching until `"` found

In the case just need to set a var with the int:

```
vid=$(. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_ID)
```